# How does Azure Fluid Relay authenticate and authorize end users of an application?

Tags: azure

I'm looking to use the new Azure Fluid Relay service in my application and want to know more details about how Azure Fluid Relay authenticates users, and how the JWTs encode and verify data within the context of the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application host needs to authenticate the end users. Once that is done, it creates a JWT and signs it with the secret provided to you during the provisioning of the Fluid Relay resource. This token is what the service uses to authorize that user for this collaborative session.

For more details please see this documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-fluid-relay/concepts/authentication-authorization